# Call an API when the user clicks everytime on a link in UI in React js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, graphql

I have a link in UI, clicking on that link pass a value and based on that value API is called and pdf will be generated, code is given below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useGetInvoicePdfQuery } from 'your-api-library'; // Replace with your actual import

function App() {
  const [pdfBlob, setPdfBlob] = useState<Blob | null>(null);
  const [pdfUrl, setPdfUrl] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [headerSkValue, setHeaderSkValue] = useState<number | null>(null);

  const { data, loading, error } = useGetInvoicePdfQuery({
    query: invoicePdfQuery,
    variables: {
      hdrSk: headerSkValue,
    },
    skip: headerSkValue === null, // Skip the query until headerSkValue is set
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      // Convert Base64 response to a PDF blob
      const decodedPdfData = window.atob(data);
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(decodedPdfData.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < decodedPdfData.length; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = decodedPdfData.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      const pdfBlob = new Blob([byteArray.buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      setPdfBlob(pdfBlob);

      // Create object URL to display PDF
      const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
      setPdfUrl(pdfUrl);

      // Open the PDF in a new tab immediately after setting headerSkValue
      if (headerSkValue !== null) {
        window.open(pdfUrl, '_blank');
      }
    }
  }, [data, headerSkValue]);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    // Set headerSkValue to trigger the API call
    setHeaderSkValue(yourHeaderValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Open PDF in New Tab</button>
      {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {error && <p>Error: {error.message}</p>}
      {pdfBlob && (
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleOpenPdfInNewTab}>Open PDF in New Tab</button>
          <object
            data={pdfUrl}
            type="application/pdf"
            width="100%"
            height="600px"
          >
            Your browser does not support PDFs.
          </object>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Link is listing in each row of a table, when clicked on the link a value is passed.
So now it's working on first time clicking on the link, second time API call is not happening.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you saying that this `useGetInvoicePdfQuery` doesn't retrigger a query request? What links are you referring to? Can you [edit] to clarify the issue/problem and to include all relevant code you are working with for a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: All relevant code is here.  On first click it's working, second click API is not calling

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing the useEffect and just putting all of your query logic in a single handler function.

````
const [pdfUrl, setPdfUrl] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [headerSkValue, setHeaderSkValue] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const { data, loading, error, refetch } = useGetInvoicePdfQuery({
    query: invoicePdfQuery,
    variables: {
      hdrSk: headerSkValue,
    },
    skip: true, // Skip the query at first
  });

  const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    // Set headerSkValue and refetch the data
    setHeaderSkValue(yourHeaderValue);
    const { data } = await refetch({ hdrSk: yourHeaderValue }); // you only need to refetch the data with yourHeaderValue here

    if (data) {
      // Convert Base64 response to a PDF blob
      const decodedPdfData = window.atob(data);
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(decodedPdfData.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < decodedPdfData.length; i++) {
        byteArray[i] = decodedPdfData.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      const pdfBlob = new Blob([byteArray.buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' });

      // Create object URL to display PDF
      const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
      setPdfUrl(pdfUrl);

      // Open the PDF in a new tab
      window.open(pdfUrl, '_blank');
    }
  };

return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Open PDF in New Tab</button>
    ...
    ```
````

Comment: const { data } = await refetch({ hdrSk: yourHeaderValue }); This throwing an error, Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Comment: Did you try it with 0 arguments? If it works I'll edit